# How to invoke a function written in html root script from a react component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, react-hooks

How to invoke a function which is present at root html script from react component which is somewhere in children react-dom?

- root.html

  ```
  <html>
     <head> 
      <script type="text/javascript">           
        function NotifyWebView()    
        {            
          window.external.notify('Text');    
        }             
    </script> 
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id='root'></div>
  </body>
  </html>
  ```
- index.tsx

  ```
  componentDidMount{
   //How to access and invoke NotifyWebView() ??
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the function to the window object.

root.html

```js
window.NotifyWebView = function () { 
 // ...your code
}
```

index.tsx

```js
componentDidMount() {
 window.NotifyWebView && window.NotifyWebView();
}
```

I see you are using Typescript, and it will complain that property "NotifyWebView" does not exist in the window object. Then you need to declare it. Add this at the end of the `index.tsx` file:

```js
declare global {
 interface Window {
  NotifyWebView?(): void // Make it optional
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the function in child component as below

```
declare function NotifyWebView();
```

Then call the function from any method of child component

```
NotifyWebView();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create function in separate file and import that function in react component then call a function in component let's say on button click or if there are nested component then can pass as a prop.